# How to call a method using mouseenter in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to call a component method on `mouseEnter` but I am not able to get any out of that.

any one clarify the way how we have to call a method on `mouseenter` in emberjs?

here is my componet hbs:

```
<h1 mouseEnter={{action "showCaution"}}>Enter on me </h1>
```

my component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions:{
    showCaution : function(){
        alert("hi");
    }
  }
});
```

But not working. here is the [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs)

Answer (score 1):

I have updated my template file like this:

```
<h1 onMouseEnter={{action "showCaution"}}>Enter on me </h1>
```

it works fine.

Comment: You should also be able to use `<h1 {{action "showCaution" on="mouseenter"}}>`